# Laravel how to insert one product to many categories

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I tried but it duplicated products, I wish to save one product under many category for one product_id.
Here my View Create (Product)

```
<div class="form-group row" id="category">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-from-label">{{translate('Category')}} <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <select class="form-control ml-selectpicker" name="category_id" id="category_id" data-live-search="true" required>
                                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                                <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->getTranslation('name') }}</option>
                                @foreach ($category->childrenCategories as $childCategory)
                                @include('categories.child_category', ['child_category' => $childCategory])
                                @endforeach
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And Here My control ( Create product )

```
   /**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::where('parent_id', 0)
        ->where('digital', 0)
        ->with('childrenCategories')
        ->get();

    return view('backend.product.products.create', compact('categories'));
}
```

And for save

```
$product->category_id = $request->category_id;
```

Here My model:

```
 public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

I believe that there function like
$product->Categories()->sync([1, 3, 4]);

Comment: `belongsTo` is a `one-to-many` (or inversely `many-to-one`), but `sync()` is only available on a `many-to-many` (via `belongsToMany()` relationship). You likely want to use that type of relationship, since in real-world situations, a Product can have many Categories, and a Category is generally shared between many Products. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many for reference

Comment: Can you help me with explain more please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if You want to store a product under many categories then. You have to change Your Relationship to Many-to-many(a products can have many categories and a categories have many products).
So You have to create Three Tables

1. Products- to store products
2. categories- to store categories
3. category_products- pivot table

Then Your Models Will be Like below
Products Model

```
 public function categories(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

Category Model

```
public function products(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

Then You can Simply use the function `sync()` to store a products under many categories
[Many to many relationships in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: How About control ? No need to add any code?

Comment: @DanubeLLC `$product->categories()->sync([1, 3, 4]);`

Comment: I got error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::sync()

Comment: Can anyone explain what i have to create in category_product table?

Comment: you can read the laravel many to many relationships here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many